# WPF MDI add Mahapps metro style

Tags: c#, wpf, mdi, mahapps.metro

I want to use [Mahapps](https://mahapps.com/) style on [WPF.MDI](https://github.com/dutts/wpfmdi).
I managed to add the style to UserControl, with resource merging, but child is unchanged.

Need to create new them for WPF.MDI, that targets mahapps style?

Any direction helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out, on my own.
Short explanation here:
Created a copy of Aero.xaml, modified it and referenced [Mahapps](https://mahapps.com/).
Source on [GitHub](https://github.com/Tory05/wpfmdi).
[image]

I reconfigured to use resource dictionary and fixed window control highlight (close, minimize, maximize).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nice work!

To use the Accent defined in the application resources, I deleted accent defined in Metro.xaml. The remaining problem is the Accent of Inactive Window.

"WPF.MDI\Themes\Metro.xaml", commented out line 10-12:

```
<!-- Deleted to use Accent defined in App.xaml -->
<!--
<Color x:Key="AccentColor">#CC161717</Color>
<Color x:Key="AccentBaseColor">#CC161717</Color>
<Color x:Key="AccentColor2">#868686</Color>
-->
```

Comment: This should be a comment.
Note if you use this, you lose the highlight of the close, maximize and minimize button on the active window.
The Inactive Window accent is correct, bring up a window in front of the mainwindow and you will see the same (gray) result.

Comment: (Note if you use this, you lose the highlight of the close, maximize and minimize button on the active window.)
Yes. The highlights is gone. It would be nice if highlights are not lost same to inactive window.

(The Inactive Window accent is correct.)
Sorry. You are right.

Comment: originally I made this for my own project... I updated it, now you can use resource accent and the highlights are also working, see on github (remove black accent code). When I have time, I will make it work with the Thememanager. If you have any new ideas post it on github, any advancement/fix is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Your work is big help to everyone especially that MahApps is gaining more popularity (I think). Thank you very much.